# Transposing a matrix using c++

Tags: c++, pointers, matrix

I want to write a program to transpose a n*n matrix, but the code output something wired. It did not transpose the matrix. suppose I want to transpose a matrix{(1,2,3), {4,5,6),(7,8,9)}, the result is basically the same as the original one with some strange behavior which I have no knowledge of.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
using namespace std;
void transpose(int* p, int n);
#define M 20
int main()
{
    int a[M][M];
    int n;      
    int* p;
    cout << "The size of a matrix is: ";
    cin >> n;
    cout << "Input a matrix: " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            cin >> a[i][j];
    p = &a[0][0];
    transpose(p, n);
    cout << "Now, the matrix is: " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {

        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            cout << setw(4) << a[i][j];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}

void transpose(int* p, int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i; j < n; j++)
        {
            int temp = *(p + i * n + j);
            *(p + i * n + j) = *(p + j * n + i);
            *(p + j * n + i) = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see any C++ code here. I only see C code here. If this were C++ code, I'd expect to see std::vector, rather than plain, garden-variety, two-dimensional arrays.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik it's not valid C, but it is valid C++.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik cout, endl, << operator.  while it may under utilize some useful C++ standard library components, it is certainly not C.

Answer (score 4):

You should call:

```
transpose(p, M);
```

instead of:

```
transpose(p, n);
```

Although your matrix is `3x3`, you reserved memory for a `20x20` matrix. So the next row is `20` `int`s  away from that (the memory gap between two row offsets is called the *stride*).

To speed up the process, you can implement a three-parameter variant:

```
void transpose(int* p, int m, int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = i; j < n; j++) {
            int temp = *(p + i * m + j);
            *(p + i * m + j) = *(p + j * m + i);
            *(p + j * m + i) = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

and call with:

```
transpose(p, M, n);
```

But to be honest, I think the way you define the matrix in memory as well as the transpose algorithm can be improved. Your `transpose` method is not really *cache-friendly*. For fast computations, I would advice the [LAPACK](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) package. Such algorithms work *block-wise* to reduce the number of *cache-faults* significantly and in make use of *multithreading* as well to boost performance. See [this lecture](http://www.umiacs.umd.edu/~ramani/cmsc828e_gpusci/Lecture11.pdf) for more details on how to transpose a matrix efficiently.

Comment: Right, in other words, the "stride" used in `transpose()` is wrong.  The three-parameter `transpose()` is a good solution; a great one would be to only store `n * n` values in the first place.

Comment: @JohnZwinck: see updated answer, but to be honest, one better uses a package, many researchers at my department made important contributions to such packages with algorithms designed for both dense/sparse matrices that are extremely optimized. Chances are pretty small that a self-written algorithm will beat them.